# Slow deceleration with BLDC and PSU

Tags: arduino, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller

I am trying to build a mini centrifuge using a generic brand 1400KV brushless motor ([looks identical to this](https://www.jsumo.com/a2212-1400kv-outrunner-brushless-motor)) and a generic 30A ESC ([identical to this one](https://www.jsumo.com/30a-basic-esc)) controlled by an Arduino Nano and powered by an old computer PSU that can supply 16A. I would like to achieve a slow deceleration as the 3D-printed rotor is quite lightweight and stops rather abruptly on stop signal. The ESC I am using is a cheap one and doesn't seem to be programmable so I am thinking of increasing the weight of the rotor. As I have little electronics knowledge I don't really know if the back current from the motor will be a problem if the motor continues rotating for a while after the ESC stops.

I have several low ESR 330uF 25V capacitors that I was considering connecting between the power cables of the ESC to prevent voltage ripples between the power supply and the ESC. Would that help to store the current from the decelerating motor or is the ESC capable of handling that? Or is there another way of achieving softer deceleration? Thanks for all the input.

Comment: Why not just ramp down the speed signal to the ESC instead of stopping it abruptly?

Comment: It might be helpful if someone explained the interface between the Arduino and the ESC. The product descriptions are vague.

Comment: @TimWescott I am planning to do so. But it doesn't stop very smoothly even at the lowest rotation speed I can reach (probably due to the magnets stopping it at fixed positions)